# Upgrading from BOX APIs V1 to V2

Tags: box-api

I am working on upgrading the synchronization layer for a web application with the box account and I am in the middle of the way and have some questions:

1. Is there a way to get the full structure for the folders and the documents with one request? My other solution it to make multiple requests for each folder to get its contains (folders and files)
2. Tags APIs in V2 is not yet added, is there a certain confirmed date to have it ready? Tags is important in our application.
3. Authorization, I am using the same values used in API V1 as a header (Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={0}&auth_token={1}) (one system account) without the need to use the refresh token to get a new authorization token every while. Is this going to work in the future?
4. Is there a way to call a service or web api on our web application side every time a user tried to delete a document from box to check if this document can be deleted or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There isn't a 1:1 equivalent of get_account_tree in V2. You'll need to make recursive GET /folders/:id/items calls in order to get the entire folder tree

2) We will be adding tags in V2 but don't have a definitive date at this point.

3) No. V1 authentication will be deprecated along with the V1 API. You'll need to port your app over to using OAuth 2.

4) You may want to check into the /events API for doing this: http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-for-a-user

Comment: it's been 2 years and it seems tags are still not returned. any closer to having an ETA?